# IBM MQ Consume from one queue in a Gateway load balanced setup

Tags: load-balancing, ibm-mq, gateway

I tried looking for a solution, but could not find in any forums. I wouldnt define this as a problem, but trying to check if there's a better way of connecting to two different QMs(Gateway QM Load balanced) using one queue. Our IBM MQ setup is exactly as in the link [Gateway loadbalancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvYjY.png)

This is a well working setup for us, but specially for production, we have to make sure to deploy two consumers to consume from two different local queues in (QM1,QM2) which is an overhead. Is it possible to create something like an alias so we just have one consumer, pointing to one queue. This makes maintenance much easier, considering the number of services we have. If anyone has accomplished this, I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: In my opinion the architecture given in the picture is a good one. The queue managers are in a cluster with gateway distributing messages to cluster queues in other two queue managers. This way even if one queue manager or consumer/service goes down you still have the other service processing messages. Having just one consumer can lead to single point of failures, consumer may not be able cope with load.

Comment: @Shashi Thanks much for the response. Makes much sense but wondering if its possible to route the messages to one queue. Like you said, event if one of the QM goes offline, the other QM would be up and the service would still be able to receive. As for the service we are deploying in docker/kube platform where availability is not an issue.

Comment: If queue managers are in a cluster and you have cluster queue defined in both queue manager, then you can remove one instance of the cluster queue. So all messages from gateway will be routed to the only one cluster queue. Your services can get messages from the lone instance of queue. Running service in a docker/kube is ok. But what about queue manager(s)? or queue manager availability is not a issue at all for you?

Comment: @Shashi QM availability is an issue. As you rightly pointed out the gateway QM setup serves the purpose of FT & LB. Think I'll live with having multiple consumers on the service side. Thanks much..